# Error when trying to escape " in php for command line

Tags: php, regex

I am starting with

```
http://myurl.com/helloworld.html","asdfa
```

and I am expecting after my regex is run

```
http://myurl.com/helloworld.html
```

I have the following php command

```
echo shell_exec("cat /tmp/urls | grep -Eo '^[^"]+'");
```

But I get no result when it runs.

When I run straight from command line with the following it works

```
$cat /tmp/urls | grep -Eo '^[^"]+'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\"` in your php-string is actually `"`, so if you want it to actually be `\"` you should escape both the double-quote `"` and the slash `\`:

```
echo shell_exec("cat /tmp/urls | grep -Eo '^[^\\\"]+'");
```

Another option is to use a single quote (and not double), however note that here you do need to escape the single-quotes inside the string:

```
echo shell_exec('cat /tmp/urls | grep -Eo \'^[^\"]+\'');
```

## update

Based on the comment your code should be:

```
echo shell_exec("cat /tmp/urls | grep -Eo '^[^\"]+'");
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually only want it to be [^"] that was an error